# Removing "View Pocket List" from Firefox's bookmarks menu

Tags: firefox

How can I remove "View Pocket List" from the bookmarks menu?

[image: View Pocket List]

Setting *browser.pocket.enabled* to *False* in *about:config* is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I remove "view Pocket List" menu entry in "Bookmarks"?

This depends on the version of Firefox you are running.

---

#### Firefox 38.0.5+

> New versions of Firefox (38.0.5 and up) have Pocket built into the toolbar and bookmark menu. If you prefer not to use Pocket for Firefox, follow these steps to disable it.
>
> **Remove Pocket from your toolbar or menu**
>
> Removing Pocket from your toolbar or menu will disable it:
>
> 1. Right-click on the Pocket icon [image: Pocket button] .
> 2. Select "Remove from Toolbar".
>
>    [image: remove pocket]

---

#### Older versions of Firefox

Add the following code to the `userChrome.css` file.

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

#menu_pocket, #menu_pocketSeparator,
#BMB_pocket, #BMB_pocketSeparator {
    display:none !important;
}
```

See also:

> http://kb.mozillazine.org/userChrome.css
>   http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration
>
> The preferred way to disable Pocket is to keep browser.pocket.enabled
>   set to true and move the Pocket toolbar button to the Customize
>   palette (right-click: Remove from Toolbar/Menu).
>
> The Pocket code only adds the menu items if the button is not in the
>   customize palette.
>
> https://support.mozilla.org/kb/disable-pocket-firefox
>
> Bug 1163917 - The built-in Pocket is NOT completely disabled if Pocket
>   is already installed and used as an add-on

Source [How do I remove "view Pocket List" menu entry in "Bookmarks"?](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2939093)

Comment: Thanks for this (partial?) solution. The problem is that the current code only _hides_ the menu item, it does not disable the menu item. If anybody knows how to kill this "pocket" invasion completely, please write!

Comment: To add, with the latest Firefox (44.0.2) no custom JS is needed, the quickest way is to right-click the toolbar button as described in https://support.mozilla.org/kb/disable-pocket-firefox

Answer (score 1):

I am using version 46 of Firefox but it's the same in versions 44 and 45. 
There are two "pockets" in Firefox. One is an 'add-on' on the Firefox toolbar on the right of the address bar, and the red "pocket" icon displayed on the Bookmarks menu as shown in the question on top of this page.

The toolbar 'add-on' icon can be dragged off the toolbar in "customize" mode. The Bookmarks display can be removed in the configuration menu. To access this menu, type 'about:config' the address bar. Then, type 'pocket' in the configuration page search bar. This lists all entries containing the word 'pocket'. On the list, find the this entry:

*extensions.pocket.enabled = true*

Double click it to change its value from 'true' to 'false'. This will remove the pocket from the Bookmarks menu.

Answer (score 0):

In about:config    go to browser.uiCustomization.state and right-click/Modify.
Navigate to "bookmarks-menu-button" and delete the pocket entry following including the parentheses and following comma. Reload and "view pocket list" will be gone.

To permanently eliminate pocket,while you are in config, search "pocket"
Modify/delete all strings in string keys.(especially get.pocket) Toggle all Boolean keys to False. Pocket is gone and won't come back unless you update/re-install FF.